# Software to compare two images in diff size, to know if the small image exists in large image or not

Tags: programming, comparison

so the case is I have a large picture (name as screenshot)
and second pic is the smallest (name as reference).

so the program will check and tell if the reference pic exist in large picture or not (no matter where location is).

is there any program that similar?

---

if not, It seems that I should make it :( . Any recommended software programing beside "MathLab" that can compare pixel between different image?

---

anyway here is the sample of large pic and small pic to be easily understood of what I need.

large pic:
[large pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sO8IlGciyJAgl2U2KAgXsFo8Hgkgw84Q)

small pic:
[refr pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13xw2vtWBTHx_kfJZh0JVvog3nLwni-Kd)

Many Thanks.

Comment: What OS shall it run on? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach with Python and the Python image-manipulation library [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/). The program scans through the larger image one pixel at a time looking for an exact duplicate of the smaller image.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

haystack, needle = (np.array(Image.open(x)) for x in sys.argv[1:3])

for y in range(haystack.shape[0] - needle.shape[0]):
    for x in range(haystack.shape[1] - needle.shape[1]):
        if np.array_equal(
                 haystack[y : (y + needle.shape[0]), x : (x + needle.shape[1])],
                 needle):
            print("Found at", (x, y))
            exit()

print("Not found")
```

When invoked as `python3 subimage.py Capture01.png referenceSamplePic.png` on my machine, it prints `Found at (426, 128)` after about 2 seconds.